# ERROR Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations'). TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations')

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, typeerror

I installed `@react-native-community/cli-platform-android` in my react-native project, now I am getting "error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations').
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations')" on running `npm run android`.

Comment: Any luck with this? I just ran across the same thing today.

Comment: I have the same problem, I use the command react-native init to create new and fresh react native project, but when I run project get error.

Comment: Any update with this? Just above I'm getting this from a new react native project.

Answer (score 26):

if the issue happening for you on react native v0.68.2,
you should change the file under:

```
node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/index.js
```

(was line 102 for me).

```
function dependencyConfig(folder, userConfig) {
// const configurations = userConfig.configurations || [];
    let configurations="";
```

this fixes the crash due to `userConfig` being empty (not sure if it's a bug or bad config)

then run `react-native run-android` normally

Comment: This solved my issue, but feels super sketchy... should prolly open a ticket on the github about this :/

Comment: This breaks `pod install` for me. Getting "Unknown configuration whitelisted: . CocoaPods found debug and release, did you mean one of these?". Check my suggested solution bellow.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. Turns out it was just a compatibility issue.
Just execute `yarn list --pattern @react-native-community/cli` or `npm list @react-native-community/cli` to see what version you're on and what version you should be on. I had to downgrade to fix the problem.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  There's a version compatibility table at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#compatibility

Comment: The message can be tricky - it seems like it is having problems with `@react-native-community/cli` but it does not have to be necessarly true - I had to update `react-native-macos` which had transitive dependency, its own copy of `@react-native-community/cli` inside with version 7x

Answer (score 6):

Patch `node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/index.js`

like this:

```
-  const configurations = userConfig.configurations || [];
+  let configurations = [];
+  if(userConfig) {
+    configurations = userConfig.configurations || [];
+  }
```

Not sure why this is needed, but it works.

Comment: However it seems to break auto linking for some reason.

Comment: Yeah this completely breaks auto linking which is no good.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm list @react-native-community/cli` and install the react-native-community/cli version displayed (e.g. `npm i react-native-community/cli@version`)

Answer (score 0):

path `node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/index.js`

Remove This Line

```
const configurations = userConfig.configurations || [];
```

Add This Line

```
 let configurations = [];
 if(userConfig) {
   configurations = userConfig.configurations || [];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

just follow simple steps:

1. npm install react-native@version
2. pod install

hopefully this time pod will install

Answer (score 0):

path **node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/index.js**

find this line

> const configurations = userConfig.configurations || [];

add a question mark after userConfig

> const configurations = userConfig?.configurations || [];